# sass showing this while compiling 'Cannot find module'

Tags: javascript, json, sass, bootstrap-5

I installed sass with npm
$npm install sass
then I made a script in JSON
but it didn't run kept showing an error 'Cannot find module'

Comment: What's your question, exactly? [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It started working when I installed sass as
devDependencies

```
$npm i --save-dev sass
```

and don't forget to give the

```
--watch
```

flag on the package.json

```
"scripts": {
"sass": "sass --watch scss:assets/css"
},
```